Jetson Orin Nano not connecting with mobile usb tethering (jetpack 6)
I am trying to connect my Jetson Nano with usb tethering to share credentials of mobile hotspot so that it can connect to my mobile's hotspot from next boot. But jetson orin nano is not connecting with my usb tethering.
[  416.459614] usb 1-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 8 [  416.793986] usb 1-2.3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using tegra-xusb
On switching on usb tethering this is the output of dmesg
